# Need to figure out why my Python Program isn't working (sorting - alphabetizing)

Tags: python

The instructions were to:  Write a Python program that reads in an two or more strings from the command line and
displays them sorted alphabetically.
Basic Requirements
- Validate inputs
- Proper error handling
- Sorts two or or more words passed as program arguments
- Correct documentation
- Proper documentation mean that the top of the file should
contain your name, the program’s name, the purpose of the
program and an example invocation of the program. Also
documentation complex or confusing lines in your code.
However, there should not be too many of those.

My code:

```
# mySorter.py. 
# This program reads two or more strings as program
# arguments and displays them sorted.
# Program will sort alphabetically the words from a string provided by the 
user
# Take input from the user
my_str = input("Enter a string: ")

# breakdown the string into a list of words
words = my_str.split()

# sort the list
words.sort()

for word in words:
print(word)

if len(my_str.split()) < 2:
print("Please provide more than one word.")
```

Apparently, I am doing something wrong.  I was told that This program does not meet the requirements. It has to read arguments passed to the program when the program is started.Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Your indentation is wonky but there's nothing obviously wrong with the sorting. You'll need to provide a use-case, i.e. an example input, that gives the wrong answer. `if len(my_str.split()) < 2:` is not a good validation, since it comes after the logic and gives no opportunity for the user to re-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# mySorter.py. 
# This program reads two or more strings as program
# arguments and displays them sorted.
# Program will sort alphabetically the words from a string provided by the user

# Simply run this program as follows:
# python your_script.py "hello user"

import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('my_str',help = 'User string')
args = argparser.parse_args()
if args.my_str:
    my_str = args.my_str

    # breakdown the string into a list of words
    words = my_str.split()

    if len(words) <= 1:
        print("Please provide more than one word.")
    else:
        # sort the list
        words.sort()

        for word in words:
            print(word)
else:
    print('No words to sort!')
    print('Try the following: python my_script.py "hello world"')
```

The requirement of "It has to read arguments passed to the program when the program is started." to me, tells me you need to use argparser to send a string without being prompted by an input().
Which explains why you aren't meeting it, since you aren't currently doing this :-)

Comment: Thank You!  It works, but it will not let user type in words without " ".

Answer (score 0):

> I was told that This program does not meet the requirements. It has to read arguments passed to the program when the program is started

Instead of using `input()` to prompt the user for strings, I think they want you to use something like `sys.argv` to get the list of input strings that you need to sort from the command line, e.g. `python myscript.py str1 str2 str3`.

Slightly modified for python3 from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm, put the following into a "test.py" file:

```
import sys

print('Number of arguments: {} arguments'.format(len(sys.argv)))
print('Argument List: {}'.format(sys.argv))
```

At the command line, do:

```
python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This produces the following result:

```
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

To get the arguments excluding the script name, you can do something like `words = sys.argv[1:]`. This will return a list of arguments starting with the second one. You  can then go ahead and sort your list as per your original program.